# Work flow for using AND adding OSM-Data

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I produce printed maps out from OSM-Data. While I work with the data, I find some missing places, names or something to fix and I would like to change/add it to OSM directly. But for several reasons I have to do my work with a local OSM-Copy (osm2pgsql).

My work flow:
I download the OSM-Area of interest and import it into a local PostGIS database. Then I do some SQL queries to fit my needs. I style and edit with QGIS. If I have to correct something, I do it on my local DB. At last the result will be printed...

I'm looking for a new work flow, so that my changes and adds are uploaded to OSM, so that anyone else can use it!

I could do my changes directly to OSM and wait at least one week to download the updated data. For some large-scale projects I do that already, but my small scale works have to be just in time - I often can't wait for the next OSM extract.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS had a plugin for editing and uploading OSM data, but that was dropped due to lack of maintenance. Currently, no OSM user authentication is stored inside QGIS, and there is no plan to do it.

OSM editors have a lot of testing routines before you can upload things. These would have to be added to QGIS too. And simply copying things to the OSM server will leave unconnected lines, duplicated POIs as points and polygons etc.

I do it this way:

- Select the new things you want to put in the OSM database
- convert polygons to lines if necessary
- save them as GPX waypoints and tracks in EPSG:4326
- Load the GPX into JOSM
- Dowload data along the GPX (it needs at least one track for that)
- Add the features, with respect to the existing data (merge nodes etc)
- Upload to the OSM server